# Как выбрать записи за текущую неделю?

Tags: mysql

У меня в базе есть запись о дате в формате UNIX, я пытаюсь выбрать записи за текущую неделю:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_add`, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

но тут понятное дело что выбирает все записи за последние 7 дней. А мне же нужно именно за текущую неделю.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND WEEK(date, {mode}) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE, {mode})`. Выбрать/ указать `{mode}` в зависимости от того, что считается "неделей". https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: Альтернативно можно получить из CURRENT_DATE дату первого дня текущей недели: `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) - {adjust} DAY`, где `{adjust}` - поправка, опять-таки зависящая от понятия "неделя".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению(*или к счастью*) ни один из ответов или комментариев не помог сделать желаемую выборку из базы по дате в UNIX.

Но с задачей справился, привожу код сюда, может кому-то поможет.

Выбор записей за текущую неделю:

> WHERE year( FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') ) = year(now()) and week(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'), 1) = week(now(), 1)

Выбор записей за текущий месяц:

> WHERE month( FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') ) = month(now()) and year( FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') ) = year(now())

week(date, N) где N - номер дня с которого начинается неделя (0 - с воскресенья, 1 - с понедельника)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

попробуйте так

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]